# Where are costs for weapons listed in the Beginner Box?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, pathfinder-beginner-box

Just got the box and are we are making characters and have gotten to equipment, the weapons have no costs in the book (unlike equipment and armor). Does that mean the character should just pick their own weapons freely (1 melee and 1 ranged) when starting?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually written right in the book, but unlike equipment and armor which has it in a big font on Orange background in the upper right corner, weapon cost is in a small black font in the lower left corner along with the other weapon stats

Comment: Adding where in the basic set you found the costs would make for a much better answer.

Comment: To expand on Weaveworker's comment: the question posed (by you) was "*where* are costs...?" It's absolutely fine to answer your own questions, but you should actually answer the question when you do so. So go ahead and put in a few lines with the solution to the problem you had. That way, when someone else has it they can find the Q&A that wasn't here when you came looking.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a page reference here.  The more detail you include, the better your answer will be.